# How to calculate `action_mroot`

Tags: transactions, eosio-code, action

### UPDATE #3 for future `action_mroot` calculators:

The two critical bits of info needed to do this (that are neither easy to find nor documented) are:

- There exists an extra `action` (which has a receipt) in every block that's called the `onblock` action. This is not reported on most block-explorers and requires a plugin on your node in order to get it.
- The `action_mroot` is calculated from the serialized `action_receipts` (including the `onblock` action) and **not** the serialized `actions` themselves.

I can't post any code despite now being able to calculate the `action_mroot` correctly because alas the Rust that I've written is currently private/proprietary. That said, it's easy to get the code itself from the EOS codebase, that difficulty was in finding out the above two pieces of information.

---

### UPDATE #2:

So per @conr2d's comment on his answer & @riccardo's elaboration, it turns out that the `action_digest` in the merkle function in the EOS code base is **not** using the `action_digest` within an action, but is calculating a *different* digest using the entire `action_receipt`.

This unfortunate naming collision appears to be the root (harr) of this whole issue.

---

### UPDATE #1:

So @conr2d's answer has shed some light on the situation but **the puzzle is still unsolved**.

With @conr2d's help we now know that in blocks which bloks.io report as having *zero* actions and *zero* transactions there actually **is** one action!

It's called the `onblock` action and it occurs in every block. Bloks.io doesn't bother to report for some reason. [This higher precision block explorer](https://jungle.eosq.app/) *does* include this extra hidden action though, but not in the format we need it.

#### The still incorrect calculation:

And so now instead consider the Jungle block **#56234435** which [bloks.io reports as having **zero** actions](https://jungle.bloks.io/block/56234435) but which [Eosq correctly shows with **one** action](https://jungle.eosq.app/block/035a11c36d2b0e2273b4f8ad8e653132f9818723f3cc654ff8430f1c41022b50).

Diving into that action we find the action itself:

```
"act" : {
    "account" : "eosio",
    "name" : "onblock",
    "authorization" : [ {
        "actor" : "eosio",
        "permission" : "active"
    } ],
    "data" : "ee9f854a500f7598aaa9d4650000035a11c19eada85e71976a9d04cb26c767ec25fa590830bec03ebf8746d7630795c33c4d4f672b0da40a7c96eb4ae7c18a25613cae2f377d2df6891c889b06fc73746a81d348db1fa682ee525bfd4cef4ea7d915aaaf4b973be1886716d3dadd1c0100000000"
}
```

...along with the `action_digest` of `a6a370c6569034a4cc41935dd88f83d1c64e0414580872f29d87f69fe7a5d769`.

However **the problem still remains**, because the block in question's `action_mroot` is `6cd473b189a292bd520cac3430cc7934273da81cc3417376194a5d757b4abdc8`

Per the **merkle** function posted below in the original question, a merkle tree made over *a single digest* should **have that digest as its root**.

But here, that's clearly not the case!

#### Tl;dr:

How to calculate the `action_mroot` of:
**`6cd473b189a292bd520cac3430cc7934273da81cc3417376194a5d757b4abdc8`**

...from this single `action_digest` of:
**`a6a370c6569034a4cc41935dd88f83d1c64e0414580872f29d87f69fe7a5d769`**?

**What ELSE am I missing?**

---

### The Original Question:

So given the **[Jungle Testnet block #55033985](https://jungle.bloks.io/block/55033985)** that has:

- an **`action_mroot`** of `7f3d...9928`
- **one** action with a digest of `e6a5...c058` ([from the tx here](https://jungle.bloks.io/transaction/676374292026946304c6b2b5ea6eeadd2c81ac1841aa4edca228ac38e6cca3c5?tab=raw))

My question is: 
**How to calculate `7f3d...9928` from `e6a5...c058`??**

---

Looking through the EOS codebase, I know that it's using **`sha256`** as it's hashing function. I've also read that the **`action_mroot`** is the root of a merkle-tree over all the actions retired in the block. ([Source for that here.](https://steemit.com/eos/@dan/inter-blockchain-communication-via-merkle-proofs-with-eos-io))

Digging into the source shows [the function that calculates the **`action_merkle`** to look like so](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/a2317d380de2ca4b8753673ee42fdfd6fb1b4819/libraries/chain/controller.cpp#L1965):

```cpp
   checksum256_type calculate_action_merkle() {
      vector<digest_type> action_digests;
      const auto& actions = pending->_block_stage.get<building_block>()._actions;
      action_digests.reserve( actions.size() );
      for( const auto& a : actions )
         action_digests.emplace_back( a.digest() );

      return merkle( move(action_digests) );
   }
```

Where [the **`merkle`** function looks like](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/905e7c85714aee4286fa180ce946f15ceb4ce73c/libraries/chain/merkle.cpp#L35):

```cpp
digest_type merkle(vector<digest_type> ids) {
   if( 0 == ids.size() ) { return digest_type(); }

   while( ids.size() > 1 ) {
      if( ids.size() % 2 )
         ids.push_back(ids.back());

      for (size_t i = 0; i < ids.size() / 2; i++) {
         ids[i] = digest_type::hash(make_canonical_pair(ids[2 * i], ids[(2 * i) + 1]));
      }

      ids.resize(ids.size() / 2);
   }

   return ids.front();
}
```

But looking at that **`merkle`** function, it would suggest that having **one** digest in the passed-in vector would mean the merkle-root would **be** that lone digest. However as we can see from the block above, that is not the case.

---

**Other things I've tried**

Having read that EOS also uses balanced merkle-trees, and that in the case where there are an odd number of leaves, the final leaf is duplicated and concatenated with itself, I tried that.

So taking the action-digest of **`e6a5...c058`** I made the two leaves by duplicating it then making one a **`canonical_left`** and the other a **`canonical_right`** (by setting or clearing the first bit):

- Left = **`66a5...c058`**
- Right = **`e6a5...c058`**

But then concatenating them together and hashing resulted in **`8742...44fc`** and so it **still didn't work** to get **`action_mroot` of `7f3d...9928``**.

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 1):

Unlike transaction_mroot (transaction_mroot is null when no trx is pushed to block), for calculating action_mroot, you should consider implicit action `eosio::onblock` which is added to block automatically. Block explorers usually omit onblock action from listing, but if you run full-node with history plugins like state_history_plugin or mongo_db_plugin, you can find the full list of actions including onblock.

Comment: Thank you conr2d - that's the first time I've seen the `onblock` action so that explains why I can't calculate the `action_mroot`!

I'm just investigating now how to get a node to return me _all_ the transactions, then to figure out how to calculate the digest of the onblock action to then try and calculate the actual `action_mroot`. I think the node I'm using has the deprecated history plugin which explains the missing actions.

But yeah, thank you so much for your help so far. If I can manage to calculate a correct `action_mroot` I'll happily accept your answer.

Comment: @gskapka, I think you're missing something because when there is no action in transaction, mroot should be created using empty action_digests object and it would be same action_mroot but that's not the case here. 

As you can see jungletest network block1 and block2 both have no transaction actions but both gives the different action_mroot.

I'm also looking into factors for calculating action_mroot and if i found something, i will share with you.

Comment: That's good, @gskapka Can you tell me the method how you did it?

Comment: I'm able to get the onblock transaction digest action from [here](https://jungle.bloks.io/transaction/38d0642a5257330633248101c7f14d637252c5dd244a76c4a32e1d1efafe90cf?tab=raw)  and actual transaction digest action from [here](https://jungle.bloks.io/transaction/d9a6d816b21e0f8fdae7e897749f9000f161d76793787ce68efcb882093eaeb1?tab=raw) but unable to calculate correct action_mroot.

Comment: The `onblock` tx has in it an action, and it's _that_ digest that you need to calculate the `action_mroot`. The issue you're facing is the same one that crippled me for so long: blocks.io is _not_ giving you all the information inside the block. The `onblock` action doesn't appear on the bloks.io block explorer at all!

Comment: I have actually manage to retrieve `onblock` transaction `digest` but still unable to calculate `action_mroot`.

Comment: ^We're in the same boat now. I too can get the hidden `onblock` actions but still, even in the case of a block with only ONE action, I cannot calculate the blocks `action_mroot` correctly.

I've updated the main question with new information regarding this.

Comment: @gskapka @Farhan-TroonTechnologies I forgot to mention one thing. The digests used to calculate `action_mroot` are derived from `action_receipt` rather than `action`. `action_receipt` contains additional information besides act_digest.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the `vector<digest_type> action_digests` defined in the EOS code here:

```
   checksum256_type calculate_action_merkle() {
      vector<digest_type> action_digests;
      const auto& actions = pending->_block_stage.get<building_block>()._actions;
      action_digests.reserve( actions.size() );
      for( const auto& a : actions )
         action_digests.emplace_back( a.digest() );

      return merkle( move(action_digests) );
   }
```

is the vector of the digests of the `action_receipt` and not of the `action_digest`. The `action_receipt` is defined here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/7d210b387ce5ec9089ab31e9cc0e237bceb25622/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/action_receipt.hpp

```
struct action_receipt {
      account_name                    receiver;
      digest_type                     act_digest;
      uint64_t                        global_sequence = 0; ///< total number of actions dispatched since genesis
      uint64_t                        recv_sequence   = 0; ///< total number of actions with this receiver since genesis
      flat_map<account_name,uint64_t> auth_sequence;
      fc::unsigned_int                code_sequence = 0; ///< total number of setcodes
      fc::unsigned_int                abi_sequence  = 0; ///< total number of setabis

      digest_type digest()const { return digest_type::hash(*this); }
   };
```